# How to build Python 3.4.2 from source in cygwin?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

According to the README in the Python 3.4.2 source package compilation on Cygwin should be as easy as this:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

However, the `make` command fails after a while giving me this output (i have gcc 3.4.4):

```
$ make
gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -Werror=declaration-after-statement   -I. -IInclude -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/signalmodule.c -o Modules/signalmodule.o
...
./Modules/signalmodule.c: In function ‘fill_siginfo’:
./Modules/signalmodule.c:744:5: error: ‘siginfo_t’ has no member named ‘si_band’
Makefile:1645: recipe for target `Modules/signalmodule.o' failed
make: *** [Modules/signalmodule.o] Error 1
```

I guess there are some dependencies that I need to compile?

Answer (score 4):

Python does not compile out of the box without additional patches.

I was able to compile Python 3.4.2 on cygwin with the following 2 patches:

- http://bugs.python.org/file34693/cygwin_si_band.patch
- http://bugs.python.org/file28934/0001-CYGWIN-issue13756-Python-make-fail-on-cygwin.patch